# How can I get this function to work in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am a new learner in Clojure and working on this function `no-divisors?`, where it should return true if none of the numbers between 2 and √ divide n, and false otherwise. I also need to use 2 functions inside `no-divisors`. First one is `get-divisors` which takes a number n as input and returns the all the numbers between 2 and √ inclusive. The second function is `Divides?` returns true if x divides n and false otherwise.

This is what I tried :

```clj
(defn Divides? [a b]
  (zero? (mod b a)))

(defn get_divisors [n]
 ( range 2 (Math/sqrt n)))

(println "get divisors"  (get_divisors 101))
output :get divisors (2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)

(defn no-divisors? [n]
  (->> (get_divisors n)
       (filter #(Divides? % n))
       empty?))

(println "no-divisors"(no-divisors? 9))

 //output :expected :false current: true
```

I am expecting the result to be false but it is not.  Any suggestions guys I would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `range` is not inclusive on the far end.

So your get-divisors should be:

```clj
(defn get_divisors [n]
 (range 2 (inc (int (Math/sqrt n)))))

(defn no-divisors? [n]
  (->> (get_divisors n)
       (filter #(Divides? % n))
       empty?))
```

Then calling  `no-divisors` with 9 will return false.

Answer (score 0):

When I copy and paste your definitions of Divides? and no-divisors? into a Clojure REPL, then call (no-divisors? 9), it returns false.

Comment: My bad sorry, it does return true which is as the same as expected result but I haven't used `get-divisors` function though which is what I am asking for @andy_fingerhut

Comment: I think you may have some mistakes in your question, which makes it unclear what your question actually is.  For example, you say that you need to use 2 functions inside get-divisors.  The first one is get-divisors...   Do you mean you need to use 2 functions inside no-divisors?  Then you say that both get-divisors and Divides work, but you can't get get-divisors to work.  Please edit your questions to be more clear about what is working, and what is not.

Comment: you are right, what I meant to say is to get `no-divisors` to work and I have miswritten that accidentally but it's corrected now